# Redirect all non-www domain to https://www with https

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, subdomain, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

[I used this guide](https://medium.com/faun/how-to-host-your-static-website-with-s3-cloudfront-and-set-up-an-ssl-certificate-9ee48cd701f9) to route my domain using Cloudfront to get HTTPS working for both my domain omnipointstudios.com and www.omnipointstudios.com to their respective https:// using Route 53, S3, and Cloudfront on AWS. The problem is I would like to redirect them both to https://www.omnipointstudios.com so it's uniform. Is this possible do with these 3 AWS services or is there something else I need to do??

Comment: Did you migrate DNS name server to route53?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this yes.

In Route 53 you will have two different DNS records:
 - www.omnipointstudios.com
 - omnipointstudios.com

Both of them will point to the cloudfront CDN.
On the CDN config you'll add two cnames, one for both URLs above. You'll also set the http/https setting to redirect all http to https.

Then the origin for the CDN is the s3 bucket.

Comment: That's essentially what I did but "https:// omnipointstudios.com" doesn't redirect to "https:// www.omnipointstudios.com", am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, your question wasn't clear about that. Another way to do that is have a bucket called omnipointstudios.com - set it up as a static website and in the bucket website options redirect all requests to www.omnipointstudios.com. Then in route 53 point omnipointstudios.com to s3, and www.omnipointstudios.com stays pointed to your CDN.